# SQL query to get the desired outcome

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. I want mysql query for the output as in the screenshot:

[image]

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Consider supplying us with what you've tried so far, and what kind of SQL Enginge you're using would be helpful too.

Comment: You need to use `UNION` operator for such queries.

Comment: @Jeredepp He can easily get such supplied input with `UNION` operator.

Comment: @AleksandrMochalygin Indeed he can, but he can also write a C programm which fetches the data from his Database and create a database in binary, but why would this be the wrong solution? People hire freelancers to accomplish stuff like this, that's a job not a question, and most of all not a well formed one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Table_1.Firstname, Table_2.Lastname, Table_2.RF1 AS 'RaterFirst', Table_2.RL1 AS 'RaterLast' FROM Table_1, Table_2 WHERE (Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID)
UNION
SELECT Table_1.Firstname, Table_2.Lastname, Table_2.RF2 AS 'RaterFirst', Table_2.RL2 AS 'RaterLast' FROM Table_1, Table_2 WHERE (Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID)
UNION
SELECT Table_1.Firstname, Table_2.Lastname, Table_2.RF3 AS 'RaterFirst', Table_2.RL3 AS 'RaterLast' FROM Table_1, Table_2 WHERE (Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID)
```

But I would like to inform you, that it is not proper way of designing database table Table_2
You must keep multiple record rows for each ID.
Check [First Normal Form](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: May be `ORDER BY Table_1.Firstname, Table_2.Lastname` needed to be used also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Select Firstname, Lastname, Table_2.RF1 AS Raterfirst, Table_2.RL1 AS Raterlast
From Table_1
Inner Join Table_2
ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
WHERE Raterfirst <> '' OR Raterlast <> ''

UNION

Select Firstname, Lastname, Table_2.RF2 AS Raterfirst, Table_2.RL2 AS Raterlast
From Table_1
Inner Join Table_2
ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
WHERE Raterfirst <> '' OR Raterlast <> ''

UNION 

Select Firstname, Lastname, Table_2.RF3 AS Raterfirst, Table_2.RL3 AS Raterlast
From Table_1
Inner Join Table_2
ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
WHERE Raterfirst <> '' OR Raterlast <> ''
```

You can optimize this SQL command, for example just use one `Where` expression.